# How to return error message or success message if exist when call web API using jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I work on asp.net MVC application . I face issue I can't display error message or success message  when call action `RequesterIndex`  controller Resignation .

calling API using ajax request working success only need to display error message or success message on sweet alert .

```js
public async Task RequesterIndex(ResignationRequester resignationRequester) {
  var filenumber = resignationRequester.EmpID;
  if (Session[SessionKeys.UserCode] != null) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      if (resignationRequester.DirectManager == 0) {
        resignationRequester.errorMsg = "Department Manager Must Be Bigger Than 0";
        goto InvalidModel;
      }
      if (Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.LineManager).Length < 6 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resignationRequester.LineManager.ToString())) {
        resignationRequester.errorMsg = "Length Line Manager Must Be equal 6 or More";
        goto InvalidModel;
      }
      if (Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.DirectManager).Length < 6 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resignationRequester.DirectManager.ToString())) {
        resignationRequester.errorMsg = "Length Direct Manager Must Be equal 6 or More";
        goto InvalidModel;
      }
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(resignationRequester.LineManager)) && resignationRequester.LineManagerName == null) {
        resignationRequester.errorMsg = "Line Manager Name Blank";
        goto InvalidModel;
      }
      if (julianRequestDate > 0 && SubmitionDate > 0 && julianRequestDate < SubmitionDate) {
        resignationRequester.errorMsg = "Last Worked Date Must be Bigger than Submit Date";
        goto InvalidModel;
      }

      int checkEmployeeNoExist = jde.CheckEmployeeExistOrNot(resignationRequester.EmpID);
      if (checkEmployeeNoExist >= 1) {
        resignationRequester.errorMsg = "Employee Exist Before";
        goto InvalidModel;
      }
     try {
        Workforce.InsertToReignation(resignationRequester, (string) Session[SessionKeys.Username], (DateTime) Session[SessionKeys.LastWorkingDate], noticeperiod, (int) Session[SessionKeys.UserCode]);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        resignationRequester.errorMsg = "Create Not Done Correctly";
      }

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.errorMsg)) {
        resignationRequester.successMsg = "Resignation Submission form Created successfully";
      }
    } else {
      var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
        .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
        .ToList();
      resignationRequester.errorMsg = "Some Required Fields Not Added";
      goto InvalidModel;
    }
  } else {
    resignationRequester.errorMsg = "No Data For This File No";
  }
  InvalidModel:
    ViewBag.isPostBack = true;
}
```

Expected result

display message of `resignationRequester.errorMsg` ON API AJAX Call if it exist

OR

display message of `resignationRequester.successMsg` ON API AJAX Call if it exist

meaning display result of action `RequesterIndex` calling  on sweet alert

```js
$('#btnsubmit').click(function() {
  $("#ResignationApp").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
    // Serialize the form data
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log("data is" + formData)
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("RequesterIndex", "Resignation")',
      data: formData,
      success: function(response) {
        var errorMsg = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["ErrorMessage"]))';
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Submition Request',
          text: errorMsg
        });
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // Handle any errors here
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Updated post**

if i have success message how to handle it because you mention error message only

why use this

```
 if (xhr.responseJSON.errors != []) {
```

i have errorMsg so why you use errors

also this is not error

this must generated after success response

I make console.log(reponse);
give me empty
so How to solve this please

Comment: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Do NOT assign a submit handler on click of a submit button. Your button must be a submit button and then remove `$('#btnsubmit').click(function() {` so the code is  `$("#ResignationApp").on("submit", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* rest of your script */ }); });` and remove the last `});`

Comment: if i have success message how to handle it because you mention error message only

Comment: Your **main** issue is that you are trying to run server-side code within client-code context.  The `='@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["ErrorMessage"]))'` part only runs *once* - when the page is very first loaded.  The server-side code does not execute again in your ajax success callback, it's *already coded into the HTML*.  Change to `var errorMsg = response`.

Comment: Your second issue is that your RequesterIndex (as provided) does not return any data / response.   And certainly not JSON.  Change your ajax success: to `success: function(response) { console.log(response) }` (and nothing else) to see what you're getting back (also use the network debugging tools)

Comment: I suggest you start your ajax journey with a much simpler controller-action, eg `public async Task FirstTest() { return DateTime.Now; }` and get a call to that working from js.  Then add a basic parameter, eg `public async Task SecondTest(string value) { return DateTime.Now.ToString + ": " + value; }` and pass an `input` value in the js/ajax.  Then build it up from there.

Comment: Thirdly: note that ajax `error:` is only called when there's an error with the ajax request itself - eg a 404 or an exception in the action - not just a logic error/check in your action - these will still return as a 200 and go to `success:`

Comment: Finally: protip: don't use `goto` (in general) - and the way you've used it, all paths lead to the last line.  Perhaps that's the intention, but certainly don't call it "InvalidModel" if it gets there when its valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are getting success message. I have added what I understood so far. Hope it helps.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("RequesterIndex", "Resignation")',
      data: formData,
      success: function(response) {
        var successMsg = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["SuccessMsgMessage"]))';
        Swal.fire({
              icon: 'info',
              title: 'Submition Request',
              text: successMsg
            });
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, message) {
         if (xhr.responseJSON.errors != []) {
          for (const key in xhr.responseJSON.errors) {
            const message = xhr.responseJSON.errors[key];
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Submition Request',
              text: errorMsg
            });
          }
         }
      }
 });
```

Comment: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: if i have success message how to handle it because you mention error message only

Comment: Where is toastr used? He uses SWAL

Comment: can you please post jQuery ajax complete with your modification if possible

Comment: when response success it will display error message and success message so can you help me please